# Do EF 6.1 web apps benefit from setting MultipleActiveResultSets=True

Tags: entity-framework

I used the new reverse engineering feature of EF6.1 and noticed that my web.config now set MultipleActiveResultSets=True by default. Here's the connect string that was created by the reverse engineer.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model1" connectionString="data source=X;initial catalog=identity;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=x;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

With EF is there much overhead associated with using this feature? For a typical web application is this something that I can benefit from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to be really careful how you write your queries if you choose to turn that off. setting it true by default is for your convenience (and to reduce the support requests)...